# rmagick gem won't install when bundling on mac os x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, bundle

I used brew to install imagemagick, that went ok. Typing convert in terminal I get the following:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-11-15
```

Now when I'm running `bundle install` I get the following error:

```
...lots of warnings first, then a couple of errors...
rmmain.c:1724:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MagickSupport'
features = rb_str_new2(MagickSupport);
                       ^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [rmmain.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in     /Users/phil/src/proj/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/phil/src/proj/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'` I get the same error. I get permissions error if I run without sudo.

If I run `sudo gem install rmagick`, however, it works. I get this output:

```
PhilipPro:proj phil$ sudo gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.15.4
Parsing documentation for rmagick-2.15.4
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for     ext/RMagick/RMagick2.bundle, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmagick.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmdraw.o, skipping
...

1 gem installed
```

What's going on here?

Comment: What version of OS X? Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Where does your Gemfile point to for the rmagick gem? Try bumping rmagick in the Gemfile to 2.15.4 instead of 2.13.4, there seems to be some problems with that particular version. Alternatively, execute `bundle update rmagick`.